# Compiling a flex application with services-config.xml, with an unknown context.root

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, blazeds

I would like to compile my flex application with a services-config.xml file. However, I am forced to supply a context.root.

In my setup, the context root (context path) isn't known until my .war file is named and dropped into the webapps directory.

It seems like there has to be a way to do this, but I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to define a dynamic context.root in the services-config.xml

```
<endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
```

Comment: When you use these dynamic values...how and when do they get filled in?

Comment: From here http://groups.google.com/group/flex-mojos/browse_thread/thread/1bf7bea45c1b879c/242d6a650b922d4c?#242d6a650b922d4c, server.name and server.port are defined at runtime. context.root is at compilation. If you use Flex SDK, you need to provide context.root only.